# Allure test report does not fetch correct device name on which tests were executed

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io, allure, browserstack

I have a question regarding Device Name in Allure Reporting.

I am using WebdriverIO with Mocha framework and Allure Reporting to run tests on BrowserStack.

Below is my configuration to run tests on the various iOS device:

```
{
        build: buildName,
        maxInstances: 1,
        device: "iPhone 6S Plus",
        os_version: "11",
        project: "Mobile Mobile",
        app: "Mobile-iOS",
        deviceName: "iPhone 6S Plus OS-11",
        "browserstack.debug": true,
        "browserstack.networkLogs":true,
        "appium:newCommandTimeout": 300,
        "appium:orientation": "PORTRAIT",
        "appium:default": true,
        "appium:automationName": "XCUITest"
    },

    {
        build: buildName,
        maxInstances: 1,
        device: "iPhone XS",
        os_version: "13",
        project: "Mobile Mobile",
        app: "Mobile-iOS",
        deviceName: "iPhone XS Plus OS-13",
        "browserstack.debug": true,
        "browserstack.networkLogs":true,
        "appium:newCommandTimeout": 300,
        "appium:orientation": "PORTRAIT",
        "appium:default": true,
        "appium:automationName": "XCUITest"
    },

    {
        build: buildName,
        maxInstances: 1,
        device: "iPad Pro 11 2018",
        os_version: "12",
        project: "Mobile Mobile",
        app: "Mobile-iOS",
        deviceName: "iPad Pro 11 OS-12",
        "browserstack.debug": true,
        "browserstack.networkLogs":true,
        "appium:newCommandTimeout": 300,
        "appium:orientation": "PORTRAIT",
        "appium:default": true,
        "appium:automationName": "XCUITest"
    },

    {
        build: buildName,
        maxInstances: 1,
        device: "iPad Mini 2019",
        os_version: "12",
        project: "Mobile Mobile",
        app: "Mobile-iOS",
        deviceName: "iPad Mini OS-12",
        "browserstack.debug": true,
        "browserstack.networkLogs":true,
        "appium:newCommandTimeout": 300,
        "appium:orientation": "PORTRAIT",
        "appium:default": true,
        "appium:automationName": "XCUITest"
    }
```

After tests execute on BrowserStack, Allure test results include following as device name for each tests:

`<parameter kind='argument' name='device' value='iphone-12.1'/>`

I don't understand how and from where allure gets "iphone-12.1", and why isn't Allure getting the real name of the device that was passed in the configuration?

I appreciate any help in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: I found some clue for iOS devices. Adding "appium:deviceName" property in the configuration file helps to flow device name to the Allure report.